# It's the roundest today! Add a merry feast to go with it!

Tags: riddle, story

What are Marc, Oliver, Olivia, and Noah talking about:

> Marc: It's sure round!
> Oliver: If it's not round I will eat my shoe!
> Olivia: Well, that's one opinion. It's sure gleaming off that nice bright light of hers!
> Noah: Like it do we? Well we should go and take a closer look with our glassy friend!
> Olivia: It's going to enlarge her a lot, you know.
> Marc: Well, I'm freezing. Maybe we should go in and eat our food? Remember, we only eat it once a year!
> Oliver: Oh that. I'm sure it's disgusting!
> Olivia: Go try it out. It's really yummy with the fills! Add the egg on top, homemade, round, just like it!
> Noah: Well, what are we waiting for! Happy ______________

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are they talking about?

> The Moon

When does all this take place

> During the [Mid-Autumn Festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Autumn_Festival) or **Moon Festival**

that nice bright light of hers

> Sunshine reflected off the moon

our glassy friend

> A telescope

Maybe we should go in and eat our food? Remember, we only eat it once a year!

> Mooncake is traditionally eaten once a year during the Mid-Autumn Festival

Go try it out. Its really yummy with the fills! Add the egg on top, homemade, round, just like it!

> It seems that the outer pastry is made using duck egg yolk.

Well, what are we waiting for! Happy ______________

> "Mid-Autumn" (or possibly "Moon Day") - the 15th day of the 8th lunar month

Notice the hint

> The initials of the speakers spell out **MOON**

Comment: Congratulations! The moon was round, and mind you, mooncakes are yummy!

Comment: I'm going to accept later, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @Stevo I don't mind, completely up to you